# How do you modify the background color of a label in a running Gtk3(Perl) program?

Tags: perl, gtk3

I can't seem to find the proper way to modify the background color of a label in a running Gtk3 Perl program. I can hack at the CSS and modify it there(and the hack works but its sloppy as ****) but I can't find the proper way to do it.

I tried looking at the draw event but couldn't get it to work with a label's background color.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using [`pango_attr_list_new`](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Text-Attributes.html#pango-attr-list-new):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Gtk3 -init;
use Pango;

{
    my $window = Gtk3::Window->new( 'toplevel' );
    $window->signal_connect( destroy  => sub { Gtk3->main_quit() } );
    my $label = Gtk3::Label->new('Hello world!');
    my $attrlist = Pango::AttrList->new();
    my $fontsize = 20;
    my $attr1 = Pango::AttrSize->new($fontsize * Pango::SCALE);
    $attrlist->insert($attr1);
    my $attr2 = Pango::AttrBackground->new(0x0000, 0xFFFF, 0x0000);
    $attrlist->insert( $attr2 );
    $label->set_attributes( $attrlist );
    $window->add( $label );
    $window->set_default_size( 200, 200 );
    $window->set_position('center_always');
    $window->show_all();
    Gtk3->main();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Tried the above code with a label that had no text.... Couldn't see the background results when I ran it. Added text to the label and there's the background color change.